# jQuery-1.11.3 violates CSP eval policy. Is there a fix or workaround?

Tags: jquery, security, eval, content-security-policy

I'm implementing the header `content-security-policy` and cleaning up (a mountain of) code as I go.

My main sticking point on the javascript side of things is that jQuery-1.11.3 violates the eval policy:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
```

Is there a way around this other than the unsafe `'unsafe-eval'` policy? It seems to me that to go down that route negates a large part of the security this header provides. As [Devdatta Akhawe](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2015/09/csp-the-unexpected-eval/) points out, protection against code injection does not necessarily protect against eval being used to execute code when jQuery is used.

There doesn't seem to be an awful lot about this on the [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/search/csp%20%7C%7C%20content-security-policy) and what there is is *old*.

Surely somebody somewhere has had to make decisions concerning this problem.

Comment: The fix is to upgrade recent enough jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have to take that as a no, then.

Comment: It really is pretty disturbing that I have not come across a rebuild of JQuery which includes a lack of eval statements to allow this JavaScript library to run with CSP...